# Removing isolated newlines via regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I am formatting lists. Nearly all the issues have been fixed. But there's trouble with the following:

```
$line = "137 ARBICKLE, Dougal Bruce
20 Every Street Some Town, Musician 138 ARBUCKLE, Edith"

$change = $line -replace '([\n\r])(\d)', ' $2'
$change
```

Here the sample text has NO backtick for ignoring newlines. I have simply pasted in the way it appears in original file. Because I need to replace newlines that are breaking up the text within the output lines.  The regex was tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/0lPw0h/1)

Output is:

```
 20 Every Street Some Town, Musician 138 ARBUCKLE, Edith
```

After reading [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) I tried single quotes but no dice.

I don't understand. I expected this output:

```
137 ARBICKLE, Dougal Bruce 20 Every Street Some Town, Musician 138 ARBUCKLE, Edith
```

Comment: When running your code, I get your expected output. Can't replicate this issue in PSVersion 5.1.19041.1682.

Comment: When you are in doubt where it is `\r\n` or \n\r`, you can always use `[\n\r]+` to match the end-of-line stuff, see: https://regex101.com/r/akvUOJ/1

Comment: @Luuk, `\n\r` is not a newline sequence used on any platform that I know of. By contrast, `\r\n` and `\n` are the dominant forms (leaving the obsolete `\r` aside), on Windows and Unix respectively. To match either of these, use `\r?\n`

Comment: @mklement0: Please read the explanation: "Match a single character present in the list  `[\n\r]`, and     
`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible"

Comment: @Luuk, you said "where it is`\r\n` or `\n\r`", and I pointed out that `\n\r` is not a known newline sequence. If you want to match _consecutive_ newlines in a platform-agnostic fashion, use `(?:\r?\n)+`. By contrast, your pattern would match any non-empty run of any mix of CR and LF and can therefore yield false positives (and doesn't allow limiting the match to _one_ newline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex instead:

```bash
$line -replace '\r?\n(?=\d)', ' '
```

- `\r?\n` matches both CRLF and LF-only newlines and avoids your original problem (see below).
- Also, using a look-ahead assertion (`(?=...)`)  to match the adjacent character avoids the need for capture groups.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your `$line` string contains a Windows-format CRLF newline.
- `[\n\r]` matches only *one* character, which means that only `\n` (the LF) was captured by your regex, leaving the `\r` (CR) behind in the string.

The stray CR then resulted in broken display of the result, because when the CR is printed, the cursor position is reset to the first column on the same line, with the remainder of the string being printed there.

Here's a simple demonstration of the problem:

```bash
"foo!`rbar" # -> *prints as* 'bar!'
```

Comment: Is this due to the OP being on PS Core?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, no it's about the input string using Windows-format CRLF newlines (which can happen in either edition).